# Powershell recursive filename read and rename

Tags: batch, powershell-2.0

i have downloaded from my ftp server a directory tree using wget and forcing ascii encoding so now i hve a lot of folders and files names something like "foo%C3%BC" (some of the files/folders already have correct names because they only had ascii characters).

I'm now trying toconvert them back to utf-8 using powershell, i tried writing the following line to accomplish this

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\folder -Recurse | select BaseName | Rename-Item -NewName {[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode{BaseName}}
```

but this is not working and gives me the following error

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at '@{BaseName=filename}' does not exist.
At line:1 char:88
+ ... ect BaseName | Rename-Item -NewName {[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode{BaseNam ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

over and over again (i suppose once for every file found).

The command works niecly up to the pipe after "select BaseName" so the problem is in the renaming part.

Does anyone have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: My guess is the error is thrown because you're trying to rename based only on the BaseName, which doesn't include the path.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 i thought that with the -NewName parameter i didn't have to have the path of the file (i'm not even really sure how i can get it). Do you have any suggestions on how i could try to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda late but I wanted to post an answer for people that might come across this question (I just remembered I had post  it after having found an answer)

The following snippet does exactly what i needed

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web;

# Get the filenames and order them to have the files first, this avoids problems when renaming them
$data =  get-childitem C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\folder -recurse | Sort-Object FullName -descending;

# Cycle every file
ForEach($dat in $data){

     # Get the decoded UTF-8 name
     $decoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($dat.name);

     # Rename the file if the decoded name is different than the current one
     if ($dat.name -ne $decoded){ren $dat.FullName $decoded}

}
```

The problem with my initial approach was that the folder were renamed before the files contained in it, that meant that the path of the single files was not correct anymore. I solved it by sorting the list of paths in descending order so that the single files get renamed first and added a check that will rename  a file only if its name changed due to the encoding.